# Will BA1404 circuit work with TEA5591A

Tags: transmitter, receiver, frequency-modulation

For an electronics project I would like to build stereo FM transmitter and receiver circuits. I was just wondering if these two circuits would work together.

The BA1404 circuit can be found [here](http://www.circuitstoday.com/stereo-fm-transmitter-using-ba1404).

The TEA5591A circuit can be found [here](http://electronicsproject.org/f-m-receiver/).

Comment: Are you going to keep asking [this same question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128166/fm-radio-transmitter-and-receiver-circuits) about every pair of transmitter and receive circuits you can find? The basic answer is that if the transmitted frequency and modulation depth and pre/de-emphasis are the same it will work, and you've already been told that. It's futile to keep asking the question about specific pairs, unless you get lucky and find someone who has built them both and used one to talk to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it should but the art to getting things working is breaking the job into smaller slices (metaphor warning!). For instance, build the transmitter first and test it with a regular FM radio that are cheap and easy to get hold of.

Once you are happy the transmitter is working, get the receiver working by listening into FM broadcast transmissions.

Then bring the two together and test.

A BIG WORD of warning - many countries will have laws against building and using FM transmitters. Use the shortest antenna you can to prove it works then if you decide to make the antennas bigger nobody's going to be knocking on my door.